# Python, how to keep the thread working?

Tags: python

I want to keep the thread working event if it raise an error. (python2)

The working thread:

```
def thread_update(n):
    """Send the data to server per n second."""
    while True:
        update_data()  # the function that posting data to server
        time.sleep(n)

thread_u = threading.Thread(name='thread_u', target=thread_update, args=(5,))
thread_u.start()
```

When I close the server, the thread_u will raise an error and exit:

```
Exception in thread thread_u
...
HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway
```

So I create a daemon thread to keep it working(When the thread_u is exit, I want to start it again)

The daemon thread:

```
def thread_daemon(n):
    while True:
        if not thread_u.isAlive():
            thread_u.run()
        time.sleep(n)

thread_d = threading.Thread(name='thread_d', target=thread_daemon, args(60))
thread_d.start()
```

Now the problem is that the daemon just working once and exit with the same error.

```
Exception in thread thread_u
...
HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway


Exception in thread thread_d
...
HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway
```

Is there anyway to keep the thread_d working event if it raise an error. Or is there anyway to keep the thread_u working event if it raise an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to keep your thread working, just handle the exception inside of its `run`:

```
def thread_update(n):
    while True:
        try:
            update_data()
            time.sleep(n)
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the exception.

```
try:
    update_data()
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e,file=sys.stderr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you catch the exception in `thread_update` ?

```py
import logging

def thread_update(n):
    """Send the data to server per n second."""
    while True:
        try:
            update_data()  # the function that posting data to server
        except HTTPError:
            logging.exception("meh")
        time.sleep(n)

thread_u = threading.Thread(name='thread_u', target=thread_update, args=(5,))
thread_u.start()
```